# How to generate nested associative array of specific fields from database table which has different fields?

Tags: php

> I want to generate a nested associative array from the result of SQL query from the [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sRCN.png) which should look like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => RODENTIA
        [children_no] => 3
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Sciuridae 
                        [children_no] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => Marmota 
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [name] => Marmota himalayan
                                                        [children] => Himalayan Marmot
                                                    )
                                            )
                                    )
                             )

                        ),
        [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Spalacidae 
                        [children_no] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => Cannomys
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [name] => Cannomys badius 
                                                        [children] => Lesser Bamboo Rat
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    ),
        [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Spalacidae 
                        [children_no] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => Cannomys
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [name] => Cannomys badius 
                                                        [children] => Lesser Bamboo Rat
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    ),
                    [3] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Cricetidae 
                        [children_no] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => Alticola
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [name] => Alticola roylei 
                                                        [children] => Royle's Mountain V
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

> **Problem:** I am unable to figure it out how to nest array if there are same subsequent particular column values, for example, *Rodentia* has 3 different families (according to the table) it should nest inside children array and similarly for other fields as shown in the above array. My code is as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `mamallia_table`";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $genus = array();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            foreach($result as $row){
                $data[] = classification_order($row);                   
            }
            echo "<pre>";
                print_r($data);

        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }           
    }
    function classification_order($row){

        $species[] = array("name"=>$row['species'],"children"=>$row['common_name']);
        $genus[] = array("name"=>$row['genus'],"children"=>$species);
        $family_count[] = array("name"=>$row['family'],"children_no"=>$row['no_of_species'],"children"=>$genus);
        $data = ["name"=>$row['order'],"children_no"=>$row['no_of_family'],"children"=>$family_count];

        return $data;               
    }
```

> **Output:** Which gives me the resulting array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => RODENTIA
        [children_no] => 3
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Sciuridae 
                        [children_no] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => Marmota 
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [name] => Marmota himalayan
                                                        [children] => Himalayan Marmot
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => RODENTIA
        [children_no] => 3
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Spalacidae 
                        [children_no] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => Cannomys
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [name] => Cannomys badius 
                                                        [children] => Lesser Bamboo Rat
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => RODENTIA
        [children_no] => 3
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Cricetidae 
                        [children_no] => 1
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => Alticola
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [name] => Alticola roylei 
                                                        [children] => Royle's Mountain V
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
)
```